# Google Sheet Formula to Populate the Values in Calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a whole year calendar separate for each month. Where i want to populate the Sheet2 Col"B" values according to the dates in calendar.

Your help will be appreciated.

Calendar

[image]

Sheet 2 data

[image]

Comment: Is each grid-style calendar month on it's own tab?

Comment: If you share an editable sample sheet I can show you how to do it fairly quickly all in one formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will pull the events for the Date in cell H84 (June 6th)

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(Events!$B:$B,Events!$C:$C<=H84,Events!$D:$D>=H84)))
```

Comment: I need one more favor that is it possible in Google Sheets that to create auto hyperlink. For example if any event is appear in calendar then i will click on the cell then it will take me to the concern row in Event Sheet @MattKing

Comment: like this https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/hyperlink-to-index-match-output-in-google-sheets/ @MattKing here is gif https://infoinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/index-match-hyperlink.gif